# How do I access server error-response from response with 400 status code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am logging in a user with intentionally invalid credentials and trying to send back the error response from the server ("Unable to login")

**How to access this response in my request so I can display the message to the user?**

Right now I can print the response object (see below) in Xcode *but I don't see the error message I am trying to access from the server* ( "unable to login" ) in this object??

What am I doing wrong?

**Javascript Express router code**

```
router.post(`/api/user/login`, async (req, res,) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({user, token})
    } catch (err) {
        const message = err.message     // err.message -> "unable to login"
        res.status(400).send({message}) // HOW DO I ACCESS THIS MESSAGE IN MY REQUEST?
    }
})
```

**Swift API Request**

```
static func loginUser (user: UserLogIn, completion: @escaping(Result <LoginResponse, 
NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        let user = user
        
        guard let url = URL(string: Ref.API_ROOT + Ref.LOGIN) else { return }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        do {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            urlRequest.httpBody = try encoder.encode(user)
      
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
                
                guard let jsonData = data, error == nil else {
                    if let error = error as NSError?, error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain {

                        completion(.failure(.networkError("\(error.localizedDescription)")))
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    print(response!)
                    completion(.failure(.loginError("Domain Error")))
                    return
                }
               
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.urlBuildError("Url build error"))) 
                }               
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(.unableToComplete("Unable to complete")))
        }
    }
```

**Response Object** :
**Why is my error response "unable to login" not in here?**

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x623453d12134> { URL: http://localhost:3000/api/user/login } { Status Code:
 400, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        30
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 14 Apr 2021 15:38:42 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"1e-J0jWW/rGxsghjubfgt2iegw3A\""
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} }
```

Comment: Hey did you find any workaround? I am also facing to a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

For URLSession, `HTTPURLResponse` class contains only the **metadata** associated with the HTTP response ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse)) therefore, the logged response seems correct.

In your case, I believe `res.status(400).send({message})` sends the message object in HTTP response's body. Therefore, to parse that data,

```
session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completion: @escaping(Result <LoginResponse, 
NetworkError>) -> Void) { (responseBody, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // handle transport error
    }
    let response = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let responseBody = responseBody!
    if !(200...299).contains(response.statusCode) {
        // handle HTTP server-side error
        if let responseString = String(bytes: responseBody, encoding: .utf8) {
            // The response body seems to be a valid UTF-8 string, so print that.
            // This will probably be `{"message": "unable to login"}`
            print(responseString)
        } else {
            // Otherwise print a hex dump of the body.
            print(responseBody as NSData)
        }
        completion(.failure(.loginError("Domain Error")))
        return
    }
    // Handle decoding response...
}.resume()
```

You probably would have to do some decoding since you're sending an object for the error message on node.js. Refer to the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_http_server-side_errors) on Debugging HTTP Server-Side Errors for more information.

Answer (score -1):

**Response Object : Why is my error response "unable to login" not in here?**

Because you have added the response in a `guard let` and your function is returning from there itself, and as it is not able to go ahead it never reaches to the decoding part.

```
 guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
     print(response!)
     completion(.failure(.loginError("Domain Error"))) 
     return //Returning from here
}
```

Here, when the `statusCode` is not `200` then it goes in the `else` part, inside which you are printing the `response` and then, in the next line, you have you `completionHandler` and then `return`, so it returns from there only.

If you want to see your message, you have decode the data in the `else` part like this:

```
 guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                
   do {
       let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
       completion(.success(response)) //Here you will get your errorMessage, I have not seen your LoginResponse model, I hope you have added your keys there.
       } catch let error {
            completion(.failure(.urlBuildError(error.localizedDescription))) 
          return 
      }
}
```

Here response is `URLResponse` and not the response you are expecting, please go through the `dataTaskMethod` and know what it is:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask

Comment: my LoginResponse model only has the keys "user: User" and "token: String" for decoding the successfully logged in user data and my ResponseError is an enum. Which model would I use? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know your, `JSON`, please add it above.